End points of event horizon
I am reading The Nature of Space and Time by S. W. Hawking. In the last paragraph on page 16 he said that:

event horizon may have past end points but don't have any future end points

I understand the mathematical definition of these past and future end points but I don't Know why I can't relate it here. I want to understand why he is avoiding future end points and allowing past ones?

The difference here is due to the time direction of a black hole. A past endpoint should form in the case of the natural formation of a black hole through collapsing matter. A future endpoint however may allow you to access the information within the black hole/ escape the black hole in the future.

I think he was referring to a spherical black hole without bh evaporation phenomenon. After the collapse the metric becomes the Scwartzshild one due to the Birkhoff theorem. The arising event horizon has no future endpoint there as well known...There is a past endpoint due to black hole formation itself...

@ValterMoretti why "the arising event horizon has no future end point ..."

Look at the Schwarzshild Carter Penrose diagram $i^+$ is not part of the manifold.
